# ValueError: Please initialize `TimeDistributed` layer with a `Layer` instance

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to build a model which can be trained on both audio and video samples but I get this error

`` ValueError: Please initialize `TimeDistributed` layer with a `Layer` instance. You passed: Tensor("input_13:0", shape=(None, 5, 648, 384, 3), dtype=float32) ``

Here are my three model functions:

```
def build_convnet(shape=(648, 384, 3)):
    momentum = .9 
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (2,2), input_shape=shape,padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (2,2), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=momentum))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=momentum))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=momentum))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool2D())

    print(model.summary())
    return model
```

```
def action_model(shape=(5, 648, 384, 3)):
    # Create our convnet with (112, 112, 3) input shape
    convnet = build_convnet(shape[1:])
    # then create our final model
    # model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    # add the convnet with (5, 112, 112, 3) shape
    input_shape = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape)
    TD = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(input_shape)(convnet)
    # here, you can also use tf.keras.layers.GRU or LSTM
    LSTM1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(1024)(TD)

    Dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(LSTM1)
    Drop1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.2)(Dense1)
    Dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(Drop1)
    Drop2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.2)(Dense2)
    Dense3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(Drop2)
    # Dense4 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')(Dense3)

    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input_shape,outputs=Dense3)

    return model
```

```
def audio_and_final_model():
  input_shape = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(220941,1))
  Conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(16,activation='relu',kernel_size=(10))(input_shape)
  MaxPool1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D()(Conv1)
  Dropout1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(MaxPool1)
  Conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32,activation='relu',kernel_size=(10))(Dropout1)
  MaxPool2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D()(Conv2)
  Dropout2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(MaxPool2)
  Conv3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(16,activation='relu',kernel_size=(10))(Dropout2)
  MaxPool3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D()(Conv3)
  Dropout3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(MaxPool3)
  Flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(Dropout3)
  Dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu')(Flatten)
  Dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64,activation='relu')(Dense1)


  model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input_shape,outputs=Dense2)

  return model
```

```
INSHAPEAM = (5, 648, 384, 3)
INSHAPEAFM = (220941,1)
am = action_model()
afm = audio_and_final_model()

combined = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate([am.output,afm.output])
z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,activation='softmax')(combined)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[INSHAPEAM,INSHAPEAFM],outputs=z)
```

I tried to search but I could just find one answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715928/valueerror-output-tensors-to-a-model-must-be-the-output-of-a-tensorflow-layer) but I didn't really understand it so it would be great help if someone could help me here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is this line supposed to do? TD = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(input_shape)(convnet)

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro It's a time distributed layer. Since the input here is of 5 dimensions and the video is analysed as time-series, I have added this layer. It's supposed to take a conv net as input(3 dim)

Comment: Then you have the parameters in the wrong order, it should be TD = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(convnet)(input_shape)

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Yes. I figured that out but it still shows the same error

Comment: It cannot  be literally the same error, please add the full traceback of the new error

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro i tried again and it did work out but with three other errors which I fixed till I got stuck on this one ` ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_15:0", shape=(None, 220941, 1), dtype=float32) at layer "input_15". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []`  Updated code along with error log is here https://pastebin.com/kKDsSXQh

Answer (score 3):

the problem is in the part below. change this part from the function:
just try to embed the part on build_convnet in the action model using the functional model not the sequential

```
 TD = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(convnet)(input_shape)
```

Comment: I tried combining the two functions but it still gives the same ValueError. I have uploaded the combined function here https://pastebin.com/0Uv8G5rV

Comment: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'layer' This is what it shows

Comment: try to follow this guide. https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/

Comment: Sorry but you are just confusing the OP, TimeDistributed takes a layer as first parameter, so the correct call is TimeDistributed(convnet)(input_shape).

Answer (score 0):

If somebody else encountered the same error, I had same problem and solve it by making the `build_convnet` return a `keras.Model` not Sequential.

On your example, it would be:

```
def build_convnet(shape=(648, 384, 3)):
    momentum = .9 
    input_tensor = Input(shape, name='input')
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (2,2), padding='same', acitvation='relu')(input_tensor)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (2,2), padding='same', acitvation='relu')(x)

    x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=momentum)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D()(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=momentum)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D()(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=momentum)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool2D()(x)

    return tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_tensor], outputs=[x])
```

And of course, changing the order of `convnet` and `input` in the `TimeDistributed` call as mentioned in the comments:

```
TD = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(convnet)(input_shape)
```