# CNN-LSTM error intialized Time Distributed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I am trying to build CNN-LSTM to predicting price but I get an error message when trying to build the model. The error message was

`Please initialize 'TimeDistributed layer' with a 'tf.keras.layers.Layer' instance. You passed: <keras.layers.core.Flatten object at 0x7fc70c70f250>`

Here is my CNN-LSTM model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation="relu"), input_shape=(None, n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="relu"))
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

earlyStop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=30)
```

I have search for the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59509077/valueerror-please-initialize-timedistributed-layer-with-a-layer-instance) but I couldn't really understand, would be great if could help me. Thank you!

Comment: The error tells you everything, you are mixing tf.keras and keras imports,which is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to replicate your issue as shown below

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv1D , MaxPooling1D , LSTM, TimeDistributed
from keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation="relu"), input_shape=(None, n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="relu"))
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-11436877029b> in <module>()
     11 model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=2)))
     12 model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)))
---> 13 model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
     14 model.add(LSTM(100))
     15 model.add(Dense(32))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/wrappers.py in __init__(self, layer, **kwargs)
    125           'Please initialize `TimeDistributed` layer with a '
    126           '`tf.keras.layers.Layer` instance. You passed: {input}'.format(
--> 127               input=layer))
    128     super(TimeDistributed, self).__init__(layer, **kwargs)
    129     self.supports_masking = True

ValueError: Please initialize `TimeDistributed` layer with a `tf.keras.layers.Layer` instance. You passed: <keras.layers.core.Flatten object at 0x7fe9c42d5a50>
```

**Fixed code:**

Instead of `from keras.layers import Flatten`, if you can use `from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten`, will resolve your issue.

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv1D , MaxPooling1D , LSTM, TimeDistributed, Flatten
#from keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation="relu"), input_shape=(None, n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="relu"))
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! it's really helped me