# ValueError: Please initialize `TimeDistributed` layer with a `tf.keras.layers.Layer` instance

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train this encoder-decoder lstm network.

```
def keras_encoder_decoder_lstm2(structure , args):
     n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = args.seq_len, args.feature_no, args.pred_len
     model = Sequential()
     model.add(LSTM(40, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features)))
     model.add(Dropout(structure["dropout"]))
     model.add(LSTM(units=20, return_sequences=True))
     model.add(Dropout(structure["dropout"]))
     model.add(LSTM(units=15))
     model.add(LSTM(units=40,return_sequences=True))
     model.add(Dropout(structure["dropout"]))
     model.add(LSTM(units=25,return_sequences=True))
     model.add(Dropout(structure["dropout"]))
     model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))

     return model
```

But it keeps getting me this error:
File "C:\Users\Med\anaconda3\envs\timeseries\lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\rnn\time_distributed.py", line 74, in **init**
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Please initialize `TimeDistributed` layer with a `tf.keras.layers.Layer` instance. Received: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x000001DD3DB6B9D0>
Can anyone help please?

I'm importing it as following:
`from keras.layers import TimeDistributed`

and I've tried the solution in this question:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59509077/valueerror-please-initialize-timedistributed-layer-with-a-layer-instance](https://stackoverflow.com) 
But still not working.

Comment: You need to add the imports you are using, soun ds like you are mixing the use of keras and tf.keras (not the same library).

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you